# What are some good practices for building enumerations in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Obviously atoms are the best choice for enumeration values. But these are not associated with or castable to integers.

I think struct might be the way to go. The code below works.

```
defmodule ElixirTesting do

  import ExUnit.Assertions

  defmodule IceCreamFlavorEnumeration do
    defstruct vanilla: 0, chocolate: 1, peanut_butter: 2
  end

  def test_enumeration do

    e = %IceCreamFlavorEnumeration{}

    v = e.vanilla
    c = e.chocolate
    p = e.peanut_butter

    assert v < c
    assert c < p

  end
end
```

However, integer values can be re-assigned by users of the struct. Even re-assigned to non-integer values I believe. That’s not acceptable if exposed in an API.

Consider an api such as [this](https://www.orekit.org/site-orekit-10.3.1/apidocs/index.html):

```
void addKeplerContribution(PositionAngle type, double gm, double[] pDot)
```

or one in which the integer value is used in a mathematical sense (to convert to milliseconds – this is a made-up function):

```
enum DurationType {
  MILLISECONDS = 1,
  SECONDS = 1e3,
  MINUTES = 60e3,
  ...
}
void addMilliseconds(DurationType type, double duration_value) {
  ...
  milliseconds = duration_value * (int)type;
  ...
}
```

A keyword list might be an alternative. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your title here... the code sample you showed merely demonstrates the use of a struct. Any value in a struct can be re-assigned and overwritten and there is no casting or protection of data types.  E.g. you can happily do `struct(IceCreamFlavorEnumeration, vanilla: "not an int")` and there are no errors.  You may wish to look to the Ecto package if you want more control of the data that hydrates a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We normally use pattern-matching for this.

```elixir
@type interval :: :millis | :seconds | :minutes
@spec add_interval(interval(), integer()) :: integer()
def add_interval(:millis, duration) when is_integer(duration),
  do: duration
def add_interval(:seconds, duration) when is_integer(duration),
  do: duration * 1_000
def add_interval(:minutes, duration) when is_integer(duration),
  do: duration * 1_000 * 60
```

That way might look not familiar at the first glance, but it’s the way to go. You explicitly disallow calling this function with somewhat unknown as the first parameter and you accept integers only as the second parameter.

Comment: Neat. The guards and pattern matching make sense. What does the :: symbol mean? I'm trying to find it in the getting started guides.

Comment: Also the Ecto.Enum module apparently defines a mapping between atoms and strings. Is this another way?

Comment: `::` is a [typespec](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#types-and-their-syntax). I would say `Ecto.Enum` does this because it needs to store the actual values into the DB, AFAICT.

Comment: Perfect ty, I was really confused by seeing :: in a few places in the documentation and our code.